# Set Background image width 100% height auto

Tags: css

I have a banner section as such:

```css
.bannerImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" alt="banner image" class="bannerImage" />
```

So instead of using background image, I am using an image with `width` `100%` and `height` `auto`.

Now I want to add a banner title over the banner section. So, since it is not possible to achieve the effect with just image, I am using `background-image` property now. But with background image I want the same layout like how it was with just image. The background should always take width 100% and height should be auto. Below is my approach. As you can see the section adjusts to height of content. Is it possible to set it's height to image's height.

```css
.bg_banner_image {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_banner_image" style="background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg')">some content here</div>
```

Comment: container is empty so why container take height from background image if you need container as same height as background image then you must give them  height other vice put some content in side the container

Comment: I want the container to take the height of background image not the content in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the image within it and make it hidden (By using `opacity:0;`). so that it will fit

```css
.bg_banner_image {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.bannerImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_banner_image" style="background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg')">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" alt="banner image" class="bannerImage" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.bg_banner_image {
    height: auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:relative;
}
.bg_banner_image img {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_banner_image" style="background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg')">
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" alt="banner image" class="bannerImage" />
<div class="content">
  SOME BANNER CONTENTS
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. the pseudo element `:after` will give parent a `height` because of its `padding`.

```css
.bg_banner_image {
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.bg_banner_image::after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    padding: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_banner_image" style="background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg')"></div>
```

Comment: container is just visible for padding 15%

Answer (score 0):

if want to stick with background-image. Javascript is needed, in my opinion, please review this one.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('bg_banner_image')[0],
  y = x.style.backgroundImage;

function imgSize(url) {
  var img = new Image(),
    /*in case url passed is in url(blablabla)*/
    rege = /^url\(['"](http[s]?:\/\/.*)['"]\)/,
    url = rege.test(url) ? url.match(rege)[1] : url;

  var p = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    img.onload = function(e) {
      res({ /*return height and width of original image*/
        height: e.target.naturalHeight + "px",
        width: e.target.naturalWidth + "px"
      });
    }
    img.onerror = function(e) {
      rej("error");
    }
    img.src = url;
  });
  return p;
};

/*trying to get original image width and height then change the height of div*/
imgSize(y).then(function(o) {
  x.style.height = o.height;
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err, "dunno")
});
```

```css
.bg_banner_image {
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg_banner_image" style="background-image: url('http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg')">some content here</div>

<!--for comparison only-->
<img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" width="100%" height="auto">
```